# Return value, use in other function

Tags: python

I feel like I am misunderstanding something really fundamental. I wrote a program to do some math:

```
import math
def func1(a, b, c):
    print (f"We will now square {a}, {b}, {c} and add them")
    y = (a**2) + (b**2) + (c**2)
    print (f"y = ", y)
    x = y/3
    print ("x = ", x)
    z = math.sqrt(x)
    print ("z = ", z)
    return z
func1(1, 5, 1)
```

This works, I get the desired output, which is Z.
But in my mind, I should be able to write a function, return a value, then use that value in another function. I'd like to break up the steps in the above script to see them more clearly. I was unable to do this, but succeeded in putting all the math in one step, seen above. Ideally I'd write something and it would look like this...

Func1(a, b, c)
Square numbers a,b,c. Add them then return value

Func2
Take value I returned from Func1, divide by 3. Return value.

Func3
Get square root of value from Func2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. What's stopping you?

Comment: do `result = func1(1, 5, 1)` and plug that in to a new function. E.g. `func2(result)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this just pass them in different functions as required.
eg.

```
def func1(x,y,z):
    .....
    .....
    return ans1

def func2 (ans1):
    .....
    .....
    return ans2


ans1 = func1(1,2,3)
ans2 = func2(ans1)
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Save the returned value of each function into a variable and pass it to the next function. For example:

```
import math

def func1(a, b, c):
    return (a**2) + (b**2) + (c**2)

def func2(value):
    return value/3

def func3(value):
    return math.sqrt(value)


result = func1(1, 5, 1)
print(result)
result = func2(result)
print(result)
result = func3(result)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help ::

```
import math
def func1(a, b, c):
    print (f"We will now square {a}, {b}, {c} and add them")
    y = (a**2) + (b**2) + (c**2)
    return y
def func2(y):
    x = y/3
    return x
def func3(x):
    z = math.sqrt(x)
    return z

p=func1(1, 5, 1)
q=func2(p)
r=func3(q)
print(r)
```